# Regex in PowerShell matches only first match of the line

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I need to build a script which reads the data from various log files and put the data into a csv using powershell. The output csv should have first column as the name of the log file and the second column should have some specific content from the log file.The content of the second column should not occur twice from the same file that is why the first column contains the log file name.I have managed to extract both of the type of data but my script only matches the first match using the regex pattern before putting the result in csv.

I am using following script :

```
$test = gc .\datalog.txt | Select-String -Pattern '"\w:\\\w+\\' -NotMatch |
ForEach-Object {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
D_no = [regex]::Matches($_, '^[^\:]*[^\.log:]')
D_name = [regex]::Matches($_, '((?!\\)\w+\S+(?=\\)|(\w:\w+)[^"])').Groups[1].value
    }
}
$test | Select-Object D_no, D_name | Export-Csv abc.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

D_name in my script only matches the first match on the line where as my the intended operation is to capture all the entries using the regular expression in D_name. However the regex is working fine when i am using

```
Select-String -allmatches '^[^\:]*[^\.log:]|(?!\\)\w+\S+(?=\\)|(\w:\w+)[^"]').Matches.Value
```

but this give me the data in one single column for both D_no and D_name.
 [The sample data can be found here](https://regex101.com/r/yELoRR/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `D_name` you're extracting only one match group - `Groups[1].value`. So this is the expected result. To put all the matching results into the `D_name` and then correctly export it to CSV you must combine them into a string. For example:

```
New-Object psobject -Property @{
D_no = [regex]::Matches($_, '^[^\:]*[^\.log:]').Value
D_name = ([regex]::Matches($_, '((?!\\)\w+\S+(?=\\)|(\w:\w+)[^"])') | foreach {$_.Value}) -join ','
}
```

Notice that from the first expression for `D_no` you also get a MatchCollection, but containing only 1 element. I'd suggest to grab a Value property from it.

Comment: but now the values in D_name comes in one single line, instead of individual value in each cell

Comment: First, in your question you said "content of the second column". Is it right? Second, export-csv doesn't support arbitrary number of columns. It checks the first object in pipe and include only it's properties for all others. You can try to simulate export-csv by exporting strings in which matches are separated by commas to the file (CSV format, actually)